# Problemas al levantar un servidor con Angular

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, puertos, modulos

el problema es el siguiente, cuando intento levantar en un puerto mi app de angular con el comando ng serve --open, me aparece el siguiente error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero logren ayudarme y gracias de antemano

Comment: El error te dice que el CLI de angular que usas es 10 y el proyecto con el que trabajas es la version 6. Toca bajar la version 6.0 de angular o actualizar la cli del proyecto con el que estas trabajando.

Comment: Muchas gracias Edgar